# FM for printing ZPL causes deadlock

Tags: abap, zpl, function-module

I did create a ABAP report to print some ZPL which works fine. Now my goal is to transfer that logic into a FM to be able to call it wherever and however I want. Problem is that doing so causes my SAPGUI to deadlock itself for like 10 minutes and show me a message saying "rolling area is to small".

In order to print the ZPL I used this guides:

- https://answers.sap.com/questions/3535287/printing-zpl-code-directly-to-a-printer.html
- https://blogs.sap.com/2021/07/01/print-barcode-on-zebra-printer-directly-from-abap-report-without-form/

This is the most stripped down code I tested:

```
call function 'GET_PRINT_PARAMETERS'
exporting
  destination    = 'WA06'
  copies         = 1
  list_name      = 'TEST'
  list_text      = 'Test NEW-PAGE PRINT ON'
  immediately    = 'X'
  release        = ' '
  new_list_id    = 'X'
  expiration     = 2
  layout         = 'G_RAW'
  sap_cover_page = 'X'
  receiver       = sy-uname
  department     = 'System'
  no_dialog      = abap_false
  line_count     = 60
importing
  out_parameters = params
  valid          = valid.

if valid <> space.
  new-page print on parameters params no dialog.
  format color off intensified off.
  print-control function 'BCPFX'.
  write:  /   ' :NEW-PAGE'.
  write:  /   ' ^XA ' .
  write:  /   ' ^FO040,040^A0N,40,40^FDHello World^FS '.
  write:  /   ' ^XZ ' .
  write:  /   ' ^FX End of Job'.
endif.
```

It basically just calles GET_PRINT_PARAMETERS, does some printer control voodoo and then writes the lines. This works perfectly fine when I execute that out of a SE38 report. But does absolutly nothing past showing me the printer settings windows and entering it. It just runs for like 10 minutes and then shows me the *scrolling area is too small* error which just goes away as soon as I try to hit F1 for help.

I managed to debug that FM to an extent so that I understand now that the problem lies not in my program but somewhere in the the surrounding `SFCS_FA_TEST_FUNCTION` FM or to be more precise, the deadlock occures on line 271 when executing `SFCS_FA_OUTPUT_LIST`, which consequently has a check from line 48 onwards

```
* Und dann das Ganze ausgeben
  IF rseumod-fbalv_grid = space.
    CALL SCREEN 500.
  ELSE.
    CALL SCREEN 800.     " ec: ALV-Darstellung
  ENDIF.
```

Here the CALL SCREEN 500 gets called over and over and over.

Has anyone experienced the same problem and can help me solving it?

Comment: what does your custom FM interface look like? Does that happen only when you test your FM or also when you're calling it from a report?

Comment: the FM I'm using while testing does contain 2 input parameters (MATNR and AUFN) which are currently not used in the testing FM.

Comment: The behavior of dealocking only happens when using the FM, a normal report does not produce it

Comment: sounds like the function module test environment has some issue with your FM. I've never looked at the function modules creating the test environment, but I would guess that something in the FM signature would cause the issue. But the function module that causes the issue isn't even involved in generating the FM test environment, it just displays the test data that you can save for a function module. Did you maybe re-use the function module from something else?

Comment: what about Dirk's question: *Does that happen only when you test your FM or also when you're calling it from a report?* we understand deadlock doesn't happen when running the code from report, but what about running the FM programmatically (CALL FUNCTION) from report? is it the same result as in SE37?

Comment: Ok it seems like the problem is the testing env SE37. When debugging the FM in SE37 the deadlock happens, if I create another testing report that just calls the FM it works perfectly.

Comment: Need further testing but I think that solved the issue. Will update my post. Thank you guys!

Comment: @Radinator When you found the answer yourself, then please write an own answer, post it to your own question and accept it. Self-answers are encouraged on Stackoverflow. When you just edit your question with the solution, then the system will still consider your question unanswered and present it as such to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the SE37 environment. The fact that I try to write to a printer in a FM. If I call the FM from a normal report then all works out as expected.